# When does touch: true come into effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have been reading up on the use case for calling `@model.touch` and how you can have that bubble by passing `, touch: true` when setting up your associations in the model. I think I understand everything that is happening there.

What I wanted to ask is that if at no point in your code do you call `.touch` will having associations that include `, touch: true` do anything?

I am trying to familiarise myself with a new codebase that has a handful of places that have the association set to allow `touch` to bubble but there is nowhere in the code that `.touch` is ever called. I want to try and figure out if these are redundant properties of the association or if something else can hit `.touch` that would get use out of the bubbling of it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

#### Relevant Links

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do'h!

A little more digging led me to this: [When is touch for a belongs_to in Rails triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953302/when-is-touch-for-a-belongs-to-in-rails-triggered)

Which contains the following quote:

> :touch If true, the associated object will be touched (the updated_at/on attributes set to now) when this record is either saved or destroyed. If you specify a symbol, that attribute will be updated with the current time in addition to the updated_at/on attribute.

The saved/destroyed part of this answered my question.